# Can't get Spring Security OAuth2 login to trigger

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am writing a `RESTful` web service (`Jersey` running on `Tomcat`) that needs to authenticate users' email address, and possibly access their Google Calendar.
The plan is that users will be redirected to login to Google via `OAuth2`.

My web service is already protected by `Spring Security`. It works fine with basic authentication (i.e. hard-wired list of users and passwords.) If I try to access any of the protected resources I am prompted to login.

Now I am trying to wire in `Spring Security OAuth2`. My understanding is that I will get a redirect to Google if I try to access a protected resource.

However, no matter what I try I can't seem to get OAuth to fire. There are no console errors logged, and resources are protected (I get the error "Full authentication is required to access this resource").

Something is wrong; could be my config, my understanding, or both. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

`web.xml` (partial):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/V1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>  
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
  </listener-class>  
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`spring-security.xml` (with google keys hidden):

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

    <debug />

    <oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />

    <oauth:resource id="googleOauth2Resource" 
        type="authorization_code"
        client-id="hidden"
        client-secret="hidden" 
        access-token-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v3/token"
        user-authorization-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
        scope="email" />

    <http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/V1/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <oauth:rest-template id="googleOauthRestTemplate"
        resource="googleOauth2Resource" />

    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**UPDATE:** I did find a [working demo](https://github.com/fromi/spring-google-openidconnect.git) (The name is misleading-- it is using OAuth2, not OpenID.) Accessing a protected resource triggers a redirect to Google as expected. I didn't have any luck translating his annotated classes into XML though, and I'm not running under Spring Boot or Spring MVC so it would be difficult for me to switch to using annotations.

** UPDATE 2: ** With the debugger I can see that OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter is getting called, but it decides not to redirect because the filter chain isn't throwing a UserRedirectRequiredException. (The exception being thrown by the filter chain is AccessDeniedException.)

Comment: Updated the question: I now think I know why I didn't get the default login endpoints, but I don't know how to set up what I need.

Comment: If your service is an API (no UI) then I don't see how you expect it to be able to interact with the user to get the approval from Google. Maybe you need to lift yourself up a level in the stack and look at the client of your service? Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You may be right in general. Maybe not in the specific case of consuming the API from a web page... But I think my question is more basic than that. Spring Security OAuth should redirect me to Google's page either when I hit a protected resource or when I go to a specific URL. I'm not sure which. If the former, then my config is simply not working. If the latter, then what's the endpoint? Is it something I should have included in the config?

Comment: Actually, I can be more specific. I have seen a Spring Security OAuth demo that redirects to Google when a protected resource is accessed. No special login URL. I'll edit the question down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are receiving the response: `"Full authentication is required to access this resource"` is because `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` is expecting an access token.

The `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` is used if you are a ***resource server*** accepting requests with access tokens. In your case though, it appears that your intention is to be a ***relying party*** that relies on Google to give back an access token so you can access a user's data on Google on his behalf.

So what you must do is follow the same flow as the demo app you found on GitHub:

1. The user accesses a secured endpoint `/test`
2. The user is not yet authenticated so he gets redirected to `/login` as configured in `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`
3. The request to `/login` goes through the filterchain again and is intercepted in `OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter` where its configured `OAuth2RestTemplate` attempts to retrieve user info. This throws `UserRedirectRequiredException` because the OAuth2ClientContext does not have an access token yet to retrieve the user's info.
4. `OAuth2ClientContextFilter` catches the thrown `UserRedirectRequiredException` and redirects the user to the google's authorization page.

Here's the DEBUG logs to show you the flow:

```
2016-09-11 02:32:34.361 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.366 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.367 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-09-11 02:32:34.367 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 02:32:34.375 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.378 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@38511637
2016-09-11 02:32:34.379 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.381 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.382 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /test' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-11 02:32:34.382 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.382 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.383 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.383 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.385 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.396 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.396 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.405 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID D2C2005BFB0AD21F3380BC0BE8326094 is invalid.
2016-09-11 02:32:34.405 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.406 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.407 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.415 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/test'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.421 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /test; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.422 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-09-11 02:32:34.650 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3f726a43, returned: -1
2016-09-11 02:32:34.676 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-09-11 02:32:34.678 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.678 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/test' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.679 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.679 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/test'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.679 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-09-11 02:32:34.679 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@7f127599, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.689 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.689 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing text/html
2016-09-11 02:32:34.689 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2016-09-11 02:32:34.689 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xhtml+xml
2016-09-11 02:32:34.691 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
2016-09-11 02:32:34.692 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/webp
2016-09-11 02:32:34.692 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
2016-09-11 02:32:34.697 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xml;q=0.9
2016-09-11 02:32:34.699 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
2016-09-11 02:32:34.703 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*;q=0.8
2016-09-11 02:32:34.705 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
2016-09-11 02:32:34.707 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
2016-09-11 02:32:34.707 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-09-11 02:32:34.707 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.708 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2016-09-11 02:32:34.709 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
2016-09-11 02:32:34.759 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/test]
2016-09-11 02:32:34.759 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-09-11 02:32:34.760 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/login'
2016-09-11 02:32:34.761 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 02:32:34.761 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-11 02:32:35.059 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.059 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.059 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-09-11 02:32:35.059 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7ff7af51. A new one will be created.
2016-09-11 02:32:35.060 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.060 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@38511637
2016-09-11 02:32:35.060 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.060 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.061 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-11 02:32:35.061 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.062 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.187 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%3Cclient_id%3E&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=19P08W'
2016-09-11 02:32:35.187 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-09-11 02:32:35.188 DEBUG 41435 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Also, in the sample code, take note of `@EnableOAuth2Client` which imports the `OAuth2ClientConfiguration`.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. I still don't know exactly what my problem was, but between your explanation and the debug log, I am optimistic that I could have made progress or solved it. Unfortunately that feature was sidelined and I'm on a different project now, so I may never know. :-)

Comment: @Bampfer I added some clarification for your future reference. Cheers!